# Why doesn't my Viewholder work?

Tags: nullpointerexception

So I'm creating a List for which I'm using my own implementation of the array adapter. I'm also using a viewholder for performance. But for some reason I get a nullpointer exception at this line:

```
holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
```

So I guess my holder isn't initialized? But I don't see how else my code should be?

```
public class NameViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private String[] names;
private static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView icon=null;

}

public NameViewAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,String[] names) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, names);
    this.names = names;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater li =
                (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);

        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.icon=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


        if (names[position].length() > 4)
            holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
        else
            holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);

    return convertView;
}
```

}

This is my XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

K so it seemed that the next line: 
`holder.icon=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);` 
should be changed to 
`holder.icon=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);` 
cause that's the id the ImageView has in the xml file